# VC90 Debug CRT error

Tags: visual-c++, dll, debugging, crt

I have created a Dll in VC++ 2008. But it is working with some other software (VB). Unable to load that dll function in Labview. VC90 Debug CRT error is coming. Why is this software not supporting my dll?

Comment: What error? What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you link to the dynamic crt and fail to ensure it was present on the target machine?  Try the static version (use [/MT instead of /MD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile your DLL using the debug target ? If so it will not work on systems where Visual Studio was not installed. You must publish your dll compiled in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use depends.exe (dependency walker) to find some reasons.
In your case you would choose the labview.exe in the dependency walker
and choose profile in the dependency walker.

When your dll is loaded you may see some reasons why it isn't loaded.

This actual link will lead you to the dependency walker including the profile method.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to distribute a debug CRT, espacilly with VC++ 2008 compiled binaries/DLLs. Your DLL needs the manifest file of the Debug-CRT-Dlls in the same directory.

With VC 2008 SP1 its even worse: You nned to patch you manifest files to the old version or use _BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS=1 in the stdafx.h to get the DLL running.

More infos at: [App does not run with VS 2008 SP1 DLLs, previous version works with RTM versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635/app-does-not-run-with-vs-2008-sp1-dlls-previous-version-works-with-rtm-versions)