# Compiling Qt app agains latest VC++ 2008 runtime

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008-sp1

Hi I have a problem compiling my Qt app with Visual studio 2008 SP1.

For the sake of purity I created a windows XP virtual machine, installed VS 2008, then SP1 and then compiled Qt 4.6. Now from looking at the manifest of the Qt DLLs (using XN Resource Editor) I can see that they depends on 9.0.21022.8 CRT.

But at the same time the latest CRT that comes with SP1 is 9.00.30729.4926. Why were the Qt DLLs generated with the the older manifest embedded? How can I fix this?

Besides this, on my dev machine in winsxs folder I can only find 9.00.21022.8 CRT (note double zero). Where is the 9.0.21022.8 CRT - I have no idea, but they must be somewhere((c) Bush) since the app actually starts on the dev machine.

Thanks
Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it: [App does not run with VS 2008 SP1 DLLs, previous version works with RTM versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635/app-does-not-run-with-vs-2008-sp1-dlls-previous-version-works-with-rtm-versions)