# Ordinal 12345 could not be located in dynamic link library

Tags: windows, dll

When running my freshly built application, I get the following error message:

```
Ordinal 12345 could not be located in dynamic link library mfc90u.dll
```

Apparently, my application calls a function that is not present in the given .DLL. Is there a way to determine which part of my source code that calls this function?

**Update**: I think [I'm beginning to understand what's going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635/app-does-not-run-with-vs-2008-sp1-dlls-previous-version-works-with-rtm-versions/2153085#2153085).

Comment: @JRL: I think the exact number is irrelevant. I'm only interested in the process of tracking the client code calling the unavailable function.

Comment: perhaps, but for consistency's sake... select one or the other to make your title be like your question text.

Answer (score 1):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can be an invaluable tool for problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `dumpbin /exports mfc90u.lib` to find the function that is associated with ordinal 12404.  This error typically occurs when the .lib does not match the .dll.